# Docker Compose OpenJDK - Volume Mapping not working

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute a Java Application in a container created by docker compose.

This is the compose yaml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  randomnum-generator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    image: randomnum-generator:latest
    container_name: java-randomnum-generator
```

And this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:latest
WORKDIR /app/src
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

The actual path (.) contains a "src"-folder which contains the Main.java. When I try to execute it that way, I get the error message "file not found: Main.java, Usage: javac

Am I doing something wrong with the path mapping?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to copy your Java program into the image: `COPY src/Main.java .`

Comment: Image build is different from Container Runtime. When you are compiling using `javac` in Dockerfile it has compiled the code and .class is generated. There is no need to add volume mapping to the container as this is causing overwriting to previously generated class and hence java is not able to find .class. You can try compile and run in the CMD or remove volume mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your configuration.

1. You don't specify `sourcepath` while compiling.
2. You don't need to use volumes to refer to your source/build artifacts.
3. You don't need JDK to run the application. It is only needed to build it.

Assuming you have the following file structure

```
src/Main.java
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

you can do it like this:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk AS BUILD
COPY src src
RUN javac -sourcepath src src/Main.java

FROM openjdk:11-jre
COPY --from=BUILD /src/Main.class Main.class
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  randomnum-generator:
    build: .
```

Note: if your program consists of several files you might need to include them all or build a `jar`.